# Remember the title "KKnD"?

Tags: spelling

I want to ask why in the title **"KKnD"** it's:

- **Krush**, Kill 'n' Destroy

instead of

- **Crush**, Kill 'n' Destroy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KKnD_series

I couldn't find this word in the dictionary and I've never seen it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misspelling "crush" as "krush" is a creative misspelling -- an uncommon technical term for this is "sensational spelling." From Wikipedia:

> Sensational spelling is the deliberate spelling of a word in an incorrect or non-standard way for special effect.

In English popular culture the two most common examples are:

- convenience brands that emphasize casual misspelling of a word in shorter form: cheese -> cheez, quick -> quik, easy -> EZ
- foreign styling that makes words seem as if they are written in another language -- for example, using ü and k to make band names seem more German (to reflect the Germanic branding of metal music as a genre).

"Krush" could be either a convenience styling (like kwik) or a foreign styling (like okkult) depending on context. Your example seems more like the second.

Comment: For more on this as related to brands, see the Slate article [Off Brands: Understanding the terrible spelling and punctuation in corporate names](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/the_good_word/2014/03/chick_fil_a_spelling_why_so_many_brand_names_have_spelling_and_punctuation.html).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particular about the misspelling of the word 'crush'.  It's a common thing in English-speaking popular culture - especially targeted to youth - to misspell words deliberately to appear cool and rebellious, or to make a distinctive trademark.

For just one genre, look at the heavy-metal rock bands in the 1980s that used creative misspelling, like jackal -> Jackyl and motley crew -> Motley Crue.

By changing from 'crush' to 'krush', the first 2 letters in the abbreviation are now the same.  The abbreviation is also pronounced with a pleasant assonance - "Kay Kay en Dee" vs. "See Kay en Dee".

Comment: Can anybody do it? Can I say change **"Together in the wild"** to **"Togezer in ze wild"**?

Comment: You can; but since I'm 50 years old and I don't know what you're selling, I'll look at you a little funny and wonder why you're doing it.

Comment: The "anyone" who can do this is almost always a company, a brand, a performing artist or musician or band, a show, a film or other work of art etc. In other words -- it is used with a proper noun, not a phrase.